# excel 2010 file with a chart crashes on close

Tags: excel, excel-2010, xlsx, crash

My soft is: Windows 7 64bit, Excel 2010.

I have a big excel file with about 20 pages. This file is crashing on close. I can save it, copy and so on, but on close it crash. I found one page, which crashes alone without others and put it to different file. On this page I remove all except chart. It still crashes. The problem is solving when I removing the chart. There is that file: http://ge.tt/9XOBOHa2

And there is an information about crash in russian (if it is necessary, i'll translate):

```
Сигнатура проблемы:
  Имя события проблемы: APPCRASH
  Имя приложения:   EXCEL.EXE
  Версия приложения:    14.0.4756.1000
  Отметка времени приложения:   4b9c0870
  Имя модуля с ошибкой: oart.dll
  Версия модуля с ошибкой:  14.0.4756.1000
  Отметка времени модуля с ошибкой: 4b9c0c91
  Код исключения:   c0000005
  Смещение исключения:  00000000001887e2
  Версия ОС:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Код языка:    1049

Дополнительные сведения об этой проблеме:
  LCID: 1049
  skulcid:  1049
```

Answer (score 0):

The file is crashing because your computer cannot store that much data at the same time. When you close the file, lots of memory is removed from the RAM and ROM, and the software cannot handle that. So, it crashes. Consider splitting your big Excel file into several smaller, separate files.